# How to add Battery Level indicator on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, lenovo, battery, thinkpad

I recently passed from Xbuntu from 16.04 to 20.04. With version 16.04, it was possible (by default) to see a little icon of the battery on the top right side of the screen. Now this "widget" is no longer there and I do not know how to add it. I cannot even check the battery level from any other side using the Graphical Menu.

**Walkaround**

The only way now (it is just a walkaround of course) is the command line: I just compare the battery level detected now with the full level battery using the following commands:

- for the level now:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now
```

- for the theoretical battery level:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full
```

**Question**:

The walkaround can be sometimes painful. Is there a way of adding the old widget on the Graphical User Interface? It will make me save a lot of time.

**Supplementary Info**:

The laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad T470.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact procedure to add the `New Item` is:

1. right-click on the dashboard;
2. -> `Panel` -> `New Item`
3. Search for **Power** :

[image]

and the Battery Plugin will magically appear. Thanks, @laugeo for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the dashboard, go to "dashboard", "add new element" .
Then search a "indicator power" or something similar
(as i don't use english, names  may be different)
You may need installing  `xfce4-indicator-plugin` and `indicator-power` packages

Comment: thanks for the suggestion(+1)! I find the way and added the correct procedure and terminology for the English version of Xubuntu 20.04 in the other answer!

Comment: What is the "dashboard" and where do I find it?  Please show a screenshot!

Comment: Panel  or taskbar i mean